# Would it be possible to use mediapipe's task-vision with segment-anything model?

Tags: image-segmentation, mediapipe

I recently discovered mediapipe by google : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mediapipe/tasks-vision

And I was wondering as a python noob if there is any way to use segment anything models to replace the `selfie_segmentation.tflite` model provided by google ?

I understood that maybe it is possible to convert pth > onnx > tflite
But I don't even understand if this would lead to something useable.

Could someone explain this to me ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are you looking to train a custom segmentation model, or just have a more general segmentation model? The [MediaPipe guides](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/image_segmenter#models) list the recommended models, including a more general segmentation model.